# Assign zero to diagonal cells without changing the matrix in Excel

Tags: excel, diagonal

I want to implement `LARGE()` function without changing the matrix while assigning zero to diagonal elements which can be achieved through `=IF(ROW()=COLUMN(),0,"")` if the change of base matrix is allowed.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the MAP function to create a new array from your array. Use your IF logic in the LAMBDA formula. This creates an array where all the diagonals are zeros:

```
=MAP(A1:F6,LAMBDA(a,IF(ROW(a)=COLUMN(a),0,a)))
```

Put that inside your LARGE formula, so this would take the 10th largest value from the new array:

```
=LARGE(MAP(A8:F13,LAMBDA(a,IF(ROW(a)=COLUMN(a),0,a))),10)
```

[image]