# Excel- Indirect to columnsum row after making diagonal elements 0

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

The following code indirectly refers to columnsum row in another sheet "Sheet2" in excel where "C11" is the user input for sheet name in sheet1.

Sheet 1

```
INDIRECT("'"&C2&"'!B6:E6")
```

[image]

Sheet2

[image]

|  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 334 | 199 | 451 | 258 |
| 2 | 104 | 104 | 303 | 86 |
| 3 | 919 | 443 | 289 | 81 |
| 4 | 560 | 250 | 182 | 54 |

If we are creating another Sheet3 by setting the diagonal elements to zero this formula can be used for first corresponding cell and drag it.

```
=IF(ROW()=COLUMN(),0,'Sheet1'!B2)
```

[image]

Subsequently, we can give Sheet3 in user input and get the value.

[image]

However, I want to achieve this without creating another Sheet3. Essentially, I want to refer to column sum row of the table in Sheet1 when diagonal elements are set to 0 and not modifying in Sheet1.

Comment: How do we make diagonal elements as zero?

Comment: Thought you got **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76877028/8162520)**

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya can you please post a solution with some explanation.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya I get that but these are two different steps. We want yo achieve this in one formula. Map the diagonal elements to zero and then indirect refer to  column sum row.

Comment: Can you share a little sample with expected result? I don't get the diagonal, since you reference a single row (row 155 only) also you're not summing anything. To exclude diagonal (set diagonal to zero maybe this is useful: `=ABS(MUNIT(9)-1)`

Comment: If we are creating another Sheet3 by setting the diagonal elements to zero this formula can be used for first corresponding cell and drag it.

Comment: @vp_050 yes a markdown table with expected output might help

Comment: @vp_050 it may be clear to you, but we need to be able to help you, so please post some samples and expected result(s) with that. This can help you paste data as data: https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables

Comment: I have now edited the question

Comment: It's an improvement, I know what you mean now, but using markdown we don't need to individually retype the data.

Comment: I have now edited this question

Comment: `=MMULT(COLUMN(B2:E5)^0,ABS(MUNIT(ROWS(B2:E5))-1)*Sheet2!B2:E5)` ? Not sure why you want to use indirect. Is it either Sheet2, or Sheet3 being Sheet 2 excluding the diagonal?

Comment: Sheet 1 is where we are calling the values

Comment: Yes, but you gave example of sheet2 being the complete sum, sheet3 the diagonal ignored sum. Is that all? We should avoid INDIRECT if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative approach using:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a, INDIRECT("'"&C2&"'!B2:E5"),
     b, ABS(MUNIT(ROWS(a))-1)*a,
     BYCOL(b,LAMBDA(z,SUM(z))))
```

---

Alternatively this would work as well:

```
=LET(
     a, INDIRECT("'"&C2&"'!B2:E5"),
     b, IF(ROW(a)=COLUMN(a),0,a),
     BYCOL(b,LAMBDA(z,SUM(z))))
```

---

Answer (score 2):

This may be helpful:

```
=LET(a,Sheet2!B2:E5,
MMULT(COLUMN(a)^0,ABS(MUNIT(ROWS(a))-1)*a))
```